# Make flash drive bootable with MULTIPLE Windows Installers

Tags: windows, linux, usb, grub, bootable-media

I have seen many ways to make a USB an installer for about any Windows OS. But how can I (using grub or something like that) make it bootable to all editions on Windows XP and 7?

I have tried Googling it and researching, I've even tried to do it, But I dont understand much about GRUB or linux at all.

Please keep in mind that I am not very good with linux, so please use as many details as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question. If you want a usb stick capable of installing various windows systems from ISOs, there are many programs to make this easy for you. [PendriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) is a great resource for this type of thing. Of the various choices listed there, I prefer [MultiSystem](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/).

Using its GUI, you can set up entries for each of the windows ISOs you want to use.

Comment: I used multisystem and it worked like a charm. Thanks very much for your help!